# HTML Table format for Email sending

Tags: html, html-email

I am sending a table with two columns but somehow table is not arrange properly.

Kindly see the current output at Image [image]

```
stblPRrequest = "<table style='border: 1px solid black'><tr><td style = 'border: 1px solid black'>To</td></tr><tr><td style ='border: 1px solid black'>From</td></tr><tr><td style ='border: 1px solid black'>Requested By</td></tr><tr><td style ='border: 1px solid black'>From</td>";

stblPRrequest += "<tr><th><td>Purchasing Dept</td></tr></th><tr><td>" + ddlDept.SelectedItem.Text + " </td></tr><tr><td>" + SUserName.Text + "</td></tr><tr><td> " + lblCurrentDate.Text + "</td></tr><tr><td>" + ddlCostCentre.SelectedItem.Text + " </td></tr>";
```

What I want is two columns with one table:

|-------------To-----------|----Purchasing Dept------|
|----------From----------|------Dept Name-----------|
|-----Requested By---|-----------Name-------------|
|---------From-----------|------------Country----------|

Kindly advise. Thanks.

Comment: you don't close the <tr> in the first stblPRequest. Please make sure the HTML you are using in the string is semantically 100% correct, then your table should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Brush up on basic HTML!

A two column table general structure is:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>To</td>
    <td>Purchasing Dept</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>From</td>
    <td>Dept name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also, it looks better to put a border on every td, like so:
`<td style="border: 1px solid #000000; padding: 3px;">From</td>`

(The reason you need it on every td, inline, is that some email clients do not support embedded CSS)